# `error: File "....."app/main.jsbundle does not exist` when attempting to build for iOS on Expo

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

I have for the past couple days been trying to build my app using the eas-cli for ios, but I am getting an issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

These are the problems that I am getting on Expo at the `Run fastlane` part:

```
⚠️  ld: duplicate method '+moduleName' in
┌─[category]: ExpoBridgeModule-42cab667980256920bca399fb283d4e0.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a
└─[class]: ExpoBridgeModule-f3e2a238b656aef6ef05761b66817421.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a
⚠️  ld: method '+UIDatePickerMode:' in category from /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook-dznymbkktakbescbylznhrjwttim/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-Core/libReact-Core.a(RCTDatePickerManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category
⚠️  ld: method '+UIUserInterfaceStyle:' in category from /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook-dznymbkktakbescbylznhrjwttim/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-CoreModules/libReact-CoreModules.a(RCTAlertManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category
⚠️  ld: method '+UIStatusBarAnimation:' in category from /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook-dznymbkktakbescbylznhrjwttim/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/React-CoreModules/libReact-CoreModules.a(RCTStatusBarManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category
› Generating debug LogAirTheSimpleLogbook » LogAirTheSimpleLogbook.app.dSYM
› Executing LogAirTheSimpleLogbook » Bundle React Native code and images
```

Though these are warnings, so I'm not sure if they are what is breaking the app, I then get this error:

```
❌  error: File /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook-dznymbkktakbescbylznhrjwttim/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues
```

I have tried multiple things after searching for a while but nothing have worked so far. Could anyone have an idea?

I also should probably add that when I first created the using `create-expo-app`, I moved the App.js file inside a `./src` folder that I created, but that gave me some issues so I pulled it out of there.

If it helps, these are my packages:

```
├── @babel/core@7.21.0
├── @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign@ extraneous
├── @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.11
├── @react-native-community/datetimepicker 2@ extraneous
├── @react-native-community/datetimepicker@6.7.3
├── @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.7
├── @react-navigation/native-stack@6.9.12
├── @react-navigation/native@6.1.6
├── babel-plugin-module-resolver@5.0.0
├── expo-status-bar@1.4.4
├── expo@48.0.5
├── firebase@9.17.2
├── react-native-async-storage@0.0.1
├── react-native-collapsible@1.6.0
├── react-native-dropdown-picker@5.4.4
├── react-native-flash-message@0.4.0
├── react-native-get-random-values@1.8.0
├── react-native-safe-area-context@4.5.0
├── react-native-screens@3.20.0
├── react-native@0.71.3
├── react@18.2.0
└── uuid@9.0.0
```

Thank you!

**Edit**: Just below the error message, I also get:

```
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook-dznymbkktakbescbylznhrjwttim/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook.build/Release-iphoneos/LogAirTheSimpleLogbook.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'LogAirTheSimpleLogbook' from project 'LogAirTheSimpleLogbook')
▸ (1 failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

Then re-run yarn react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios and generate the main.jsbundle file.

Then add the file to your app by right clicking XCode >> {Your App} and selecting the Add files to "{Your App Name}" option. Then select the newly created main.jsbundle file. Check if the file is added to
XCode >> {Your App} >> {Your App Target} Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources

If the file is there, rebuild the app.

kindly refer to this  solution in github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32108